# Found no Alarm clock listener in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Can anybody tell me how can I receive a broadcast when alarm clock is ringing?

For incoming call I can use PhoneStateListener. But for Alarm clock I could not find any listener.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can listen Alarm clock changes by ContentObserver

here is some code that might be help you:

```
Uri uri = Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
Handler handler = new Handler();
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, new MyContentObserver(handler));

class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver
    {
        public MyContentObserver(Handler h) {
            super(h);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.d("MyContentObserver", "MyContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange + ")");
            super.onChange(selfChange);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BroadcastReceiver.

```
public void setBroadCast() {
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Handled Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }; registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter( getPackageName() ) );

    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent( getPackageName()), 0);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
}
```

Please refer at this post [Android Broadcast Receiver](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/)

or you can read the documentation [Broadcast Receiver Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

cheers.